# Fail to convert pdf to jpg by Ghostscript on centos7

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Fail to convert pdf to jpg by Ghostscript(9.07-29)  on centos 7.5.1804. A lot of online said that need to install msttcorefonts, still error.

Anyone know how to solve the issue? thx.

PDF file:  http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H3_AP201709060860336298_1.pdf

Error log:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefined in --run--
Operand stack:
   905605   2   0   (\256\266\3637\306j\023{\342\000\017d\263\303\262\346\002\000\000\000\000)   --dict:1/1(L)--   Identity
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1867   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1167/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:292/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:23/32(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
```

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Ghostscript (9.25) complains multiple times that streams have the wrong length, but opens the file and renders it. I checked with an old version 9.07 I happen to have here, and it gave the error you quoted.

So I'd have to guess that the PDF file has a problem (ie its invalid), which old versions of Ghostscript can't deal with, but new versions have been updated to handle.

The version of Ghostscript you are using is old (the date stamp is in the log), in fact its 5 and a half years old. You should update to the current version.

I note that the PDF file was apparently modified 8 hours after it was produced, so I'd guess the application which modified it, broke it. Oh and the PDF file has been encrypted, its possible that's what caused the damage.